# How can I duplicate Passive Objects in morse simulator?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on controlling **Morse Simulator**.
[The tutorial](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.2/user/others/passive_objects.html) says we can add `Passive Objects` from same `blender file` like this:

```
import random
from morse.builder import *

# Add some randomly placed chairs
for i in range(3):
  chair = PassiveObject('props/objects','RollingChair')
  chair.translate(x=random.uniform(1.5, 7.0),
                  y=random.uniform(-5.0, 0.0),
                  z=0.0000)
  chair.rotate(z=random.uniform(0.0, 6.2)) # rotation in radians
```

But when I run this code, only one `RollingChair` is added to the scene.
I looked the source of `bpymorse` and `morsebuilder` but I couldn't figure out why I failed.